# importing lists from multiple files using a for loop in python

Tags: python, for-loop, import

This is probably quite a simple problem, but can't seem to figure it out or find any answered questions with regards to this issue.

```
xcombined=[]
for i in range (1,20):
    from 'files_'+str(i) import x
    for j in range(0,len(x)):
        xcombined.append(x[j])
```

results in the following error:

```
    import "files_"+str(i)
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I am wishing to import a list, (ie x=[15.34, ..., 15.54]) from files_1.py, files_2.py, etc and append it to another list called xcombined so that xcombined is sum of all of the "x's" from all the "files_*.py's". If I am correct 'files_'+str(i) cannot work as it isn't a string? Is there a quick way around this problem?

Thanks in advance.
Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `importlib` module here, as `import` statement doesn't work with strings.

```
import importlib
xcombined=[]
for i in range (1,20):
    mod = importlib.import_module('files_'+str(i))
    x = mod.x  # fetch `x` from the imported module
    del mod    # now delete module, so this is equivalent to: `from mod import x`
    for j in range(0,len(x)):
        xcombined.append(x[j])
```

`importlib` was introduced in py2.7, for earlier versions use `__import__`.

help on `__import__`:

```
>>> print __import__.__doc__
__import__(name, globals={}, locals={}, fromlist=[], level=-1) -> module

Import a module. Because this function is meant for use by the Python
interpreter and not for general use it is better to use
importlib.import_module() to programmatically import a module.
...
```

Comment: Does importlib exist on python 2.6 (this is the version my works linux box has). From running this, it doesn't?

Comment: @PaulWright try `__import__('files_'+str(i))` on py2.6

Answer (score 0):

From what I've understood, you're using `.py` files to store lists as python code.

This is extremely ineffective and will probably cause many problems. It's better to use simple text files (for exemple in the JSON format).

Still, here's how you should import modules with dynamically generated names:

```
import importlib
i = 1
myModule = importlib.import_module('files_'+str(i))
```